# R Shiny. Plot de una columna de un data.frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plot

He visto problemas similares pero no consigo aplicarlo al mío.
Cómo (con un data.frame que viene de fuera), plotear de forma reactiva los valores de una columna determinada (a la que he dado nombre "colname"). La idea es que sea un plot reactivo.

1. El data.frame que presento está generado para el próximo ejercicio y
   viene de una matriz 8x8.
2. Se nombran las filas y columnas para asemejarlo a una base de datos
3. Se presenta una ventana de selección para escoger el Input que
   queremos, que lo hacemos corresponder con los nombres que le hemos
   dado a las columnas del data.frame.
4. Se presenta una barra para escoger los valores de la futura x
5. Intentamos plotear de forma reactiva los valores de la columna que
   queramos en función de un x que se podría corresponder con el
   row.names o con simples números por ejemplo

Se obtiene este error:

> Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): x =
> num, y = var.
>
> Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add
> after_stat()?

Os comparto el intento de código de Shiny.

```
##
## GENERAR EL DATA.FRAME

rm(list=ls())
ls()
muestra = data.frame(matrix(1:12, nrow = 8, ncol = 8))

nombres = c()
nombrescol = c()

for (j in 1:(nrow(muestra))){ 
    
        
        nombres[j] = paste("Muestra",as.character(j),sep="_")
}

for (j in 1:(ncol(muestra))){ 
    
    
    nombrescol[j] = paste("Muestracol",as.character(j),sep="_")
    
}

row.names(muestra) = nombres
colnames(muestra) = nombrescol



##
## APP

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Prueba"),
    
    mainPanel(
        selectInput("var", label = h3("Column to plot"),
                    choices = c("", colnames(muestra)),
                    selected = NULL,
                    width='40%',
                    multiple = FALSE),
        
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 4,
               plotOutput("plot", height = 300,
                          
                          
               )
        )
    ),
    
    column(8,
           
           
           titlePanel(title=h4("Defined range")),
           
           sidebarPanel(width=7,
                        sliderInput("num", "Rango propuesto:",min = 1, max = 8,step=1,value=c(4))))
    
    
    ,
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    dat <- reactive({
        test <- muestra[muestra$num %in% seq(from=min(input$num),to=max(input$num), by=1),]
        print(test)
    })
    
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(dat(), aes(x = num, y = var)) + geom_point()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Bienvenido PabloByte a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: En ninguna parte del código has definido la columna `num`  del `data.frame` `muestra`, ahí está el error.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho!

Efectivamente me faltaba definir la columna.  He de decir que en otras versiones que hemos ido haciendo sí que lo teníamos.
De todos modos, sigue fallando el asignar `y=var` dentro del plot. Creo que no estoy siendo capaz de ligarlo bien con el InPut que pido en el desplegable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte del tema de la variable `num` que ya te había comentado, para que funcione tu código voy a sugerirte los siguientes cambios:

---

- Modificar el input con los nombres de las variables: dejar solo las variables que existen realmente y configurar el elemento inicial, esto si no lo haces hará que la aplicación muestre un error con la primer carga.

---

```
selectInput("var", label = h3("Column to plot"),
            choices = c(colnames(muestra)),
            selected = colnames(muestra)[1],
            width='40%',
            multiple = FALSE),
```

---

- Modificar el selector numérico para que funcione como un selector de rango, es necesario configurar los valores mínimos y máximos iniciales

---

```
sliderInput("num", "Rango propuesto:",
            min = 1, 
            max = 8,
            step=1,
            value=c(1, 4)
)
```

---

- La función reactiva `dat()` tiene que retornar los datos, en tú código no lo hacias

---

```
dat <- reactive({
  muestra[muestra$num %in% seq(from=min(input$num),to=max(input$num), by=1),]
})
```

---

- La definición de variables para la gráfica `ggplot` tiene su truco, no hay problema con la variable `num` por que efectivamente existe, el problema es que en `y` quieres establecer la variable a partir del combo de selección y `input$var` para `ggplot` es simplemente una cadena pero no la variable, hay que transformar esta cadena en la variable a usar:

---

```
ggplot(dat(), aes(x = num, y = !!sym(input$var))) + 
  geom_point()
```

---

Comment: Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho
Buscaré algo de info sobre el último punto que me comentas porque, pese a que el código ya funciona, no había encontrado antes nada al respecto.